# Cannot load classes from installed module

Tags: python, module, package, setuptools

I am developing a project with Python 3 and I would like to pack it as a Python module so it can be installed as a library to our machines. However I am having a problem with importing the module after installation so let me show you the code

```
├── README.txt
├── setup.py
├── virt_template
│   ├── debian
│   │   └── interfaces
│   ├── debian_platform.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── virt_template.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── virt_template_test.py
```

This is the `setup.py` content

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "virt_template",
    packages = find_packages(),
    package_data = {"virt_template" : ["debian/*"]},
    version = "1.0.0",
    author = "Petr Mensik",
    author_email = "petr.mensik@mail.cz",
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Operating System :: Linux",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    ]
)
```

Now when I run `python3 setup.py install` the module is correctly installed into `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virt_template-1.0.0-py3.4.egg/virt_template` with folder structure like this

```
├── debian
│   └── interfaces
├── debian_platform.py
├── __init__.py
├── virt_template.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── virt_template_test.py
```

So far so good, that seems correct to me. However when I do

```
from virt_template import VirtualMachine
```

I get `cannot import name VirtualMachine`. So I tried

```
from virt_template.virt_template import VirtualMachine
```

and the result is `No module named 'debian_platform'` - which is probably referring to `debian_platform.py` file.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case the correct import is

```
from virt_template.virt_template import VirtualMachine
```

Your problem is the way you import relative modules from `virt_template.py`. You should either do

```
from . import debian_platform
```

or

```
from virt_template import debian_platform
```

The root cause of your trouble is the pythonpath which is set to inside the virt_template directory when you are testing the code, and to a `site_packages` library dir when used after installation with setuptools

Comment: Thanks for answer. So what should I change about directory structure to import my module like `import virt_template`

Comment: You should not change the structure. Use one of the imports above, either full name with the package  name  in front or relative with dot. You may want to read more about [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html). That's life of a package developer. In your case you chose package name the same a your module name, this makes your import look bad. You can import your class in the topmost __init__.py. Then it will be available on the package level.

Comment: Ok, I solved it by pasting contents of `virt_template` directly in the folder with `setup.py` script, thank you for your help